# How can i execute batch file content in java on a server without window popping up

Tags: java

[image]

The uploaded Screenshot conatains the start_client.bat file content, viewed in notepad++ editor.
Currently am invoking start_client.bat on local machine it works fine but when the same bat file is invoked on server it pops up a window on server and it needs manual closure after execution. Any way to force bat file execution on server without window poppping up.

```
private void invokeSeagull(String flag) throws Exception
{

    String path="";
    if(flag.equals("Start"))
    {
        path="cmd /c start D:/Seagull/TIB/start_client.bat";
    }
    if(flag.equals("Stop"))
    {
        path="cmd /c start D:/Seagull/TIB/stop_client.bat";
    }
  try {
          String line;
          Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
          p.waitFor();
          BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
          BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
          while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
          }
          bri.close();
          while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
          }
          bre.close();
          p.waitFor();
          System.out.println("Done.");
        }
        catch (Exception err) {
          err.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Comment: What is silent mode or hidden mode or invisible mode?

Comment: Why do we need a screenshot of the script, can't you just include it in the question?

Comment: And btw, don't use screenshots, just post your code with the code formatting function

Comment: @mikea the website asks for a formatted script (code) which am unable to do it, so have posted the screenshot.ok guys got it, am new to stack community....

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet should run batch file, of course if you use Windows.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start {pathToFile}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the new in `Java 7` [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

A simple example:

```
    String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "dir"};
    ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    // Set up your work directory
    probuilder.directory(new File("c:\\stackoverflow"));

    Process process = probuilder.start();

    // Read output
    try (InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);)
    {
        String line;
        System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:\n", Arrays.toString(command));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        // Wait to get exit value
        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Fail
    }
```

Comment: According to the API, the Processbuilder should be used for all shell executions!

Comment: Your solution has some pitfalls: 1. You don't read or redirect the error-stream, if the bat-file produces a lot of output to the error-Stream, it may run full and the bat-file will get stuck, since it cannot write anymore until the stream is consumed. 2. You don't close the OutputStream, so a bat-file reading from stdin will probably get stuck (as this one with the pause command)

Comment: This is just some code that I wrote fast, it is intended to be a guide rather than a working solution that you can copy and paste. The point here is to know that you can use the new Java 7 API. In fact, I'm sure that there are some exceptions that must be catched to make this code even compile!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out be ssedano the correct way to execute shell commands in Java is the Process-builder:

```
// Just the name of an executable is enough
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "test.bat" );

pb.redirectError( Redirect.INHERIT );
pb.redirectOutput( Redirect.INHERIT );

System.out.println( String.format( "***** Running Process %s OUTPUT:", pb.command().toString() ) );
final Process process = pb.start();
process.getOutputStream().close();

final int returnCode = process.waitFor();
System.out.println( "***** Process Exited with Returncode: " + returnCode );
```

You can just redirect STDERR and STDOUT of the bat-file, so you will get all output in the Server-Output console. And you should close STDIN of the bat-file, so it will exit and not get stuck on the pause command at the end!

Comment: Can you confirm that the bat file gets executed on the server without popping up the window. Am using this particular snippet       path="cmd /c start D:/Seagull/TIB/start_client.bat";             Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path); Whenever the bat file is executed it opens up a window on the server and needs to be closed manually. Any Help......

Comment: I just tried the script on my local machine - no window pops up, it is completely silent in the background. But this could of course be different for another JavaVersion / OperatingSystem. But usually the script I provided should not pop up anything!

Comment: my jdk is 1.7u61 and am invoking a start_client.bat file of seagull which opens up a window on server , am not suppose to use scripts,  /min or /b commands to be used. any other solution other than using Runtime or ProcessBuilder class.

Comment: Ok - Am I understanding this right, it is the Seagull-Application window, which you don't want to see? So this question isn't about batch-files at all, but how to hide the seagull window?

Comment: no its the bat file itself executing in a command window open on the server, which remains unclosed and needs manual closure.         Forget about seagull, its just a 3rd party app implementing ECE(Elastic Charging Engine) which integrates with BRM(Billing & Revenue Management *oracle product*) to fetch pricing based on usage.

Comment: I just tested it with JDK 1.7.0_51 and JDK 8, both work without problems and without showing the window popup! The only difference if you want to run it on JDK 6 is you have to output the Streams manually via Streamreader

Answer (score 0):

This should run in the silent mode :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/pathto/start_client.bat"});
```

Comment: you mean to say that the bat file runs without window popping up on the server

Comment: Yes. But as friends expressed, you may assign expression returned Process object to a variable, and call waitFor() method on it, to be sure it completed before processing to next instruction.